# Can't get MSMQ to receive messages via FQDN via HTTP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, http, iis-7.5, msmq

Context - Server 2008 R2 with private queue, IIS setup. Sending messages via HTTP from other computers. [MSMQ is not in the 'default web site'. I changed the ID of my website to 1 to install msmq (after previously un installing it)]

I could do with some help. I've read through all the 'msmq messages over http just don't get delivered' and looked into this a lot, but just can't get it working.

I CAN get the queue to receive messages if I use the IP address, not if I use the FQDN that resolves to the same IP address. I need the Domain Name to work, since my next step is to get SSL to work and obviously my cert if for the full domain name!

I have a very simple app that sends the following messages:

```
Private Function SendStuff() As String

    Dim output As String = "Mesages Sent To" & Environment.NewLine

    Dim Addresses As New List(Of String)
    Addresses.Add("Direct=HTTP://46.0.0.206/msmq/Private$/test.q")
    Addresses.Add("Direct=HTTPS://46.0.0.206/msmq/Private$/test.q")
    Addresses.Add("Direct=HTTP://subdomain.domain.net/msmq/Private$/test.q")
    Addresses.Add("Direct=HTTPS://subdomain.domain.net/msmq/Private$/test.q")

    For Each address In Addresses

        Dim fullAddress As String = "FormatName:" & address

        Dim mq As New System.Messaging.MessageQueue(fullAddress)
        Dim mm As New System.Messaging.Message()


        Dim body As String = "Hello via constructor " & fullAddress

        With mm
            .Body = body
            .AcknowledgeType = Messaging.AcknowledgeTypes.None
            .UseAuthentication = False
            .TimeToReachQueue = New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0)
            .Label = address.Substring(7, 14)
        End With

        mq.Send(mm)
        output = output & Environment.NewLine & fullAddress
    Next
    Return output
End Function
```

On the server, in the IIS logs, we get exactly this:

```
2014-03-07 09:04:02 46.0.0.206 POST /msmq/private$/test.q - 80 - 83.0.0.130 - 200 0 0 31 
2014-03-07 09:04:02 46.0.0.206 POST /msmq/private$/test.q - 443 - 83.0.0.130 - 200 0 0 46
2014-03-07 09:04:02 46.0.0.206 POST /msmq/private$/test.q - 80 - 83.0.0.130 - 200 0 0 78
```

I get 1 message in the test.q, I expect 2 (both from the HTTP protocols, the httpS I don't expect yet, but would be nice :)

﻿Messages Received:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>Hello via constructor FormatName:Direct=HTTP://46.0.0.206/msmq/Private$/test.q</string>
```

Can anybody inform me on what to look at next, there's nothing of interest in the Servers/Receiving computers Event log, despite me turning on 'end to end', logging I get nothing in "applications and services log\Microsoft\Windows\MSMQ' It's got 0 messages in it.

ANY help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was simple.

It seems pretty clear all the documentation was made prior to the HTTP option, hence the lack of just one example.

You need to add a redirection for MSMQ, from FQDN.com to localhost.

You do this by adding an XML file under: C:\Windows\System32\msmq\Mapping

With the following contents:

```
<redirections xmlns="msmq-queue-redirections.xml">
  <redirection>
      <from>http://FQDN.com/msmq/private$/test.q</from>
      <to>http://localhost/msmq/private$/test.q</to> 
  </redirection>
</redirections>
```

Done

Comment: That doesn't look right. You've found a workaround, I think, for an underlying problem outside of MSMQ. You shouldn't need to redirect to localhost. Redirection is normally used when FQDN doesn't match the computername.